# errors while running pipenv on ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, pipenv, pipenv-install

I want to run `pipenv install` on my ubuntu machine with python3.10 but I get those errors when running the command:

```
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (17eb3b)...
Traceback (most recent call last):▉▉▉▉▉ 0/25 — 00:00:00
  File "/root/.local/bin/pipenv", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1128, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/cli/options.py", line 56, in main
    return super().main(*args, **kwargs, windows_expand_args=False)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1053, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1659, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1395, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 754, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/decorators.py", line 84, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 754, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/cli/command.py", line 241, in install
    site_packages=state.site_packages,
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 2102, in do_install
    keep_outdated=keep_outdated,
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 1343, in do_init
    pypi_mirror=pypi_mirror,
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 870, in do_install_dependencies
    project, normal_deps, procs, failed_deps_queue, requirements_dir, **install_kwargs
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 782, in batch_install
    use_pep517=use_pep517,
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 1519, in pip_install
    include_hashes=not ignore_hashes,
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 1438, in write_requirement_to_file
    line = requirement.line_instance.get_line(
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/requirementslib/models/requirements.py", line 2553, in line_instance
    self.line_instance = self.get_line_instance()
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/requirementslib/models/requirements.py", line 2547, in get_line_instance
    return Line(line)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/requirementslib/models/requirements.py", line 171, in __init__
    self.parse()
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/requirementslib/models/requirements.py", line 1289, in parse
    self.parse_extras()
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/requirementslib/models/requirements.py", line 577, in parse_extras
    self.line, extras = pip_shims.shims._strip_extras(self.line)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
     ▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉ 0/25 —
```

For more information, I did run `pipenv --python /usr/bin/python3.10` before that because the projects is running and build on python3.10.

Any Idea how I can fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

Somebody got the same error. It looks like problem happen with *`pip18.1`* .
So at first with run:

```
pipenv run pip --version
```

you can see your *`pip`* version and then if `pipenv` locking `18.1` of *`pip`* run one of the below commands:

```
pipenv run python -m pip install -U pip==18.0
```

or

```
pipenv run pip install pip==18.0
```

and after that you can probably run `pipenv install` successfully.

You can see more discussions for this issue in [[Running pipenv gives TypeError: 'module' object is not callable]](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/2871).

Comment: It prints me this line: `pip 21.3.1 from /root/.local/share/virtualenvs/myProject-o9T4z5yw/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)`. It says python 3.6 in here. I thought the one command I did run changed the python version to 3.10

Comment: pip version is 21.3.1 and python is 3.10.6. They already where at the latest version

Comment: i realised you need to remove the virtual env also, cause the wrong Python version is still being used. In my case mine is in the project directory, so I did `rm -rf .venv/`

Comment: this is why sometimes i just develop locally with Docker too :/